# Allowing free text in a select

Tags: c#, html

I have a widget where there is a composed component:

```
<div data-bind="visible:searchfieldvisibilityconfig.isVisible('SearchScreening_Branch')">
   @Html.CreateTypeaheadInput("widget.branch", "searchCriteria.Branch", GetValueList("ScreeningBranch"))
</div>
```

The **CreateTypeaheadInput** returns back this:

```
public static HtmlString CreateTypeaheadInput(this HtmlHelper html, string i18nKey, string valueBinding,
            ValueList valueList, params string[] additionalDataBindings)
{
    var options = string.Join("",
        valueList.Select(
            v =>
                $@"<option {GetSelectedState(v)} value=""{v.Value}""{GetCustomDataAttributes(v)} {GetAttributes(v)}>{
                        HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(v.ValueText)
                    }</option>"));

    const string template = @"<section data-bind=""validationElement: {1}"" >
            <label class=""select"">
                <select class=""input-xs {4}"" data-bind=""{3}"">{2}</select>
                <b class=""tooltip tooltip-top-right"">
                    <i class=""fa txt-color-teal""></i>
                    <span data-i18n=""{0}""></span>
                </b>
            </label>
            <div class=""note note-error"" style=""display: none;"" data-bind=""validationMessage: {1}""></div>
        </section>";

    var specificCssClass = GetSpecificCssClassForHtmlTag("select", valueBinding);
    var bindingString = $"typeahead: {{value: {valueBinding}}}, ";
    if (additionalDataBindings != null)
    {
        var additionalBindingString = string.Join(",", additionalDataBindings);
        bindingString = string.Join(",", bindingString, additionalBindingString);
    }

    return new HtmlString(string.Format(template, i18nKey, valueBinding, options, bindingString, specificCssClass));
}
```

In practice whas I currently have is a box on the UI where I am allowed to type. As soon as I start typing if there is a match between what I type and one of the values in the **valueList** then it gives me the chance to select it. This doesn't allow me to put free text unfortunately. Do you have by any chance a possible solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: At a high level it sounds like what you want is an `input`, not a `select`.  And then to implement (or use an existing tool) a kind of auto-complete on that `input`.  Something like the jQuery UI Autocomplete in terms of UX functionality.

Comment: Do you want the freetext to be a valid option on submit ?

Comment: @karthickj25 that's correct! otherwise as soon as I click away from the box the free text (since it's not one of the choices of the list) disappears